# Saying it's my first time in (a place)

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I want to say that I am visiting a place (= Japan) for the first time.

The sentences that I am thinking of are:

1. これは私に日本中を始まるです。
2. 私が日本を始まるです。

Which one sounds more correct? I am only one year into Japanese but I'm trying to learn as much as possible.

Comment: I've made some adjustments your question. (Learning resource question are off-topic here but there's a list that might contain answers to your questions about getting a native speaker penpal (http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese)

Answer (score 7):

I think you can say...

[日本]{にほん}は[初]{はじ}めてです。
(Lit. As for Japan, this is (my) first time.)

OR

日本には初めて[来]{き}ました。
(Lit. To Japan, I came for the first time.)

OR

日本に[来]{く}るのは(これが)初めてです。
日本に[来]{き}たのは(これが)初めてです。
(This is the first time I've been in Japan.)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, neither of those is correct, but you're on the right track.  What you're looking for is [初]{はじ}めて instead of 始まる.

> - 日本（に・は・には）初めてです.